# Get information of multiple Facebook groups at once

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I've gone through tons of Google searches and have run into a stumbling block with pulling in a list of Facebook groups. 
The first call goes to the api to grab  the group objects the user account is associated with:

```
$this->groups = $this->facebook->api('/me/groups');
```

This works for the basic information

```
{
     "version": 1,
     "name": "Email Friends",
     "id": "12345",
     "unread": 1,
     "bookmark_order": 12
},
```

To dig deeper I need the id for:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/374541109272246?access_token=3fasdfvartfawefwefq
```

This gets me the group information:

```
{
   "id": "12345",
    "version": 1,
   "owner": {
     "name": "someone",
    "id": "123456"
   },
   "name": "Email Friends",
   "privacy": "OPEN",
   "icon": "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/someimage.png",
   "updated_time": "2012-09-18T01:25:20+0000",
"email": "123435@groups.facebook.com"
}
```

To pull multiple groups with a single query is simple via browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=098765,32113,12345,?access_token=3fasdfvartfawefwefq
```

So working with API, or FQL, how would I be able to pull the information of multiple groups at once?

```
        $this->getFBData("groups");

        $groupsData = '<div id="gtooltip">';
        foreach ($this->groups['data'] as $data)
            { $gids .= $data['id'] .','; }

        try{
            $grpData = $this->facebook->api("/?ids=$gids");
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    error_log($e);
            return MsgBox(_t("$e"."$gids"));
        }
```

I've tried multiple variations of `facebook->api("/?ids=$gids");` and just can't get it to work right.

Comment: I figured part of it out. It gets the data, now I need to figure out how to parse it:

Answer (score 0):

I figured part of it out. It gets the data, now I need to figure out how to parse it

```
$batch = array();
        $this->getFBData("groups");

        foreach ($this->groups['data'] as $data)
            { $batch[] = array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => $data['id']); }
$grpData = $this->facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($batch), 'POST');
```

It returns a multidiemsional array:
  $var =  json_decode($grpData[0]['body'], TRUE);

Now to figure out how to loop through it all. almost there.